# Capsule holder drawer stuck in Minù Caffè Latte machine

Tags: coffee-machines

The pod drawer in my Lavazza coffee machine (model: LM600) is jammed.

I tried to pull it really hard, I tried to pry it open. I even gave a few strikes in hopes whatever is keeping it shut will shift inside. All for nothing.

I dismantled it partially, took a peek inside and retreated - with all the water tubing, that would be a major operation.

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Descaling** was the answer!

1. I mixed some vinegar with water in the tank (~1:1 ratio).
2. I turned the dial to the dispensing positing, allowed some descaling solution to go through the machine.
3. I turned the machine off and left it for a few minutes.
4. I repeated steps 2 and 3 a few times.

At some point during the process, I heard a click inside - the lock that holds the drawer during brewing came unstuck and I was now able to pull the drawer out.

More information: [Minù Caffè Latte manual with step-by-step descaling instructions](https://www.lavazza.it/content/dam/lavazza/products/manuale-macchina/manuale-minu-caffelatte.pdf)

Comment: I joined just to upvote this answer.  Thank you so much!